# Find number of AP triplets in a number stream

Tags: java, algorithm

Problem:

> Given N integers A1, A2, …. AN, Dexter wants to know how many ways he can choose three numbers such that they are three consecutive terms of an arithmetic progression.

[CodeChef link](http://www.codechef.com/problems/COUNTARI).

Here is my solution(Let "freq" be the counter)

```
 1. Create a data store (array of sorted sets) to hold a sorted set of positions of number i in stream at index i in array.
 2. for k: 0 to array.length
    a. get Sorted Set S[k]
    b. if SZ >=3, where SZ = S[k].size, compute SZ choose 3 and add it to freq
    c. for r: 2*k-1 to k
           for x in S[k]
           find entries in S[r], say A, more than x and entries in S[r-i], say B, less than x.. freq += A*B
           find entries in S[r], say A, less than x and entries in S[r-i], say B, more than x.. freq += A*B 

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

/**
 *
 * @author abhishek87
 */
class APTripletInStream {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int idx=0, numInStream;
        Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in), readLine;        

        String line = scanIn.nextLine();
        readLine = new Scanner(line);          

        DataStore dStore = new DataStore(30000 + 1);

        while(scanIn.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanIn.nextLine();
            readLine = new Scanner(line);
            while(readLine.hasNextInt()){
                numInStream = readLine.nextInt();
                dStore.add(++idx, numInStream); 
            }
            break;                       
        }
        Long res = 0L;
        try {
            res = APProblemSolver.solveProblem(dStore);  
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            res = 0L;
        }
        System.out.println(res);        
    }
}

class APProblemSolver {
    public static Long solveProblem(DataStore dStore) {
        Long freq = 0L;
        int dSize = dStore.size();
        for(int idx=1; idx<=dSize-1; idx++) {
            Set currSet = dStore.getSetAtIndex(idx);
            if(null != currSet && !currSet.isEmpty()) {

                int size = currSet.size();
                if(size >= 3) {
                    freq += (size*(long)(size-1)*(long)(size - 2)/6L);
                }

                for(int right = 2*idx-1; right > idx; right--){
                    if(right >= dSize)
                        continue;
                    Set rightSet = dStore.getSetAtIndex(right);
                    Set leftSet = dStore.getSetAtIndex(2*idx - right);
                    if(null != rightSet && null != leftSet) {
                        for(Object obj : currSet) {
                            Set leftSetHeadSet = ((TreeSet)leftSet).headSet(obj);
                            Set rightSetTailSet = ((TreeSet)rightSet).tailSet(obj);
                            freq += leftSetHeadSet.size() * rightSetTailSet.size();

                            Set leftSetTailSet = ((TreeSet)leftSet).tailSet(obj);
                            Set rightSetHeadSet = ((TreeSet)rightSet).headSet(obj);  
                            freq += leftSetTailSet.size() * rightSetHeadSet.size();
                        }
                    }
                }                
            }
        }        
        return freq;
    }           
}

class DataStore {

    private TreeSet[] list = null;
    private int size;

    public DataStore(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        list = new TreeSet[size];
    }    

    public void add(Integer idx, Integer val) {
        Set<Integer> i = list[val];
        if(null == i) {
            i = new TreeSet<Integer>();
            i.add(idx);
            list[val] = (TreeSet<Integer>)i;
        } else{
            ((TreeSet<Integer>)list[val]).add(idx);
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }    

    public Set getSetAtIndex(int idx) {
        return list[idx];
    }
}
```

Here is what I am looking for:

1. When I submit the problem, I get "time limit exceeded". Therefore I want to use NetBeans Profiler to estimate the time this solution takes so that I can improve it.
   FYI - Time limit for successful submission is 3 seconds
2. Can anyone give me some pointers to improve my solution [I DO NOT want to change my solution] by:

   - Optimizing storage
   - Which parts of my solution are time consuming and have an obvious workaround

**Example:**

Input:

```
Number Of entries - 10.
Number Stream - 3 5 3 6 3 4 10 4 5 2.
```

Output:

```
9.
```

Explanation:

```
The followings are all 9 ways to choose a triplet:
(Ai, Aj, Ak) = (3, 3, 3)
(Ai, Aj, Ak) = (3, 4, 5)
(Ai, Aj, Ak) = (3, 4, 5)
(Ai, Aj, Ak) = (3, 4, 5)
(Ai, Aj, Ak) = (3, 4, 5)
(Ai, Aj, Ak) = (6, 4, 2)
(Ai, Aj, Ak) = (6, 4, 2)
(Ai, Aj, Ak) = (3, 4, 5)
(Ai, Aj, Ak) = (3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: If would be helpful if you describe your logic in a sentence or two.

Comment: For the record you can sort the numbers.It's not a stream, you can get all the numbers, process them, and return the result.

Comment: But I do realize that position matters, so I have described my solution.

Comment: No Aravind, we cannot sort..Please find my soln described in words above..

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked your code in details but here's how I would do :

```
Sort your list -- 1
Iterate through your sorted list (i from 0 to n) -- 2
    Iterate though the remaining part of the list (j from i+1 to n) -- 2.a
        Lookup if (2*j-i) which would be the third element of the arithmetic progression -- 2.a.1
```

Step 1 is O(n*log(n)) but then it allows step 2.a.1 to be O(log(n-j)) thanks to binary search.

Here's my python implementation :

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def index_in_sorted(a, x):
    'Locate the leftmost value exactly equal to x'
    i = bisect_left(a, x)
    if i != len(a) and a[i] == x:
        return i
    return None

numbers=[4,5,6,17,9,1,442,44,32,3,21,19]
print numbers
numbers.sort()

n = len(numbers)
for i in range(0,n):
    n_i = numbers[i]
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        n_j = numbers[j]
        n_k = 2*n_j - n_i
        if index_in_sorted(numbers,n_k): # I could only process the end of numbers but it's not worth the pain
            print "Found", n_i,n_j,n_k
```

Comment: Josay,

I dont think we can sort the list.... We cannot change the position of numbers in the stream

Comment: Indeed, now that I look at the updated description, it doesn't fit your needs anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement [lazy instantiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) of your datastore.

```
public DataStore(int size) {
        for(int i=0; i<size;i++)
            list.add(i, new TreeSet<Integer>());      
    }
```

You create 30001 treesets during instantiation.
It would be much better to have map `int -> Set` of what is needed. Then in your code `dStore.getSetAtIndex(right)` if there is no set for this int , you instantiate it.

Obvious parts are:

```
for(Object objMore : leftSetTailSet) {
      for(Object objLess : rightSetHeadSet) {
          freq++;                                        
      }                                
}
```

can be changed to `freq += leftSetTailSet*rightSetHeadSet;`

Also I don't see dsStore size changing so :

instead of this: `idx<=dStore.size()-1;` in your for loop you could declare variable `dsSize = dStore.size()` and have `idx < dsSize` and `if(right >= dsSize)`

Comment: I did make the changes as you suggested but my solution is still not accepted...

I have to modify the algorithm.. looks like it is too expensive in time

Comment: I've answered your question according: [I DO NOT want to change my solution]. If you should change your algorithm - then do that and if you have problems with your next solution - ask another question

Answer (score 1):

The big idea, if you have first two terms, then the third term is fixed.

Exploiting memory you can do much better.

Let's have an array of arrays.I don't know how you do this in Java, here's the C++ version.

`vector<vector<int> > where`

**where[i]**=positions in input where **value=i**

So {1,4,2,3,3} would look like

```
where[0]={}
where[1]={0}
where[2]={2}
where[3]={3,4}
where[4]={1}
```

If you initialize the the above vector of vector where, then the positions would be sorted.

Again you can set first 2 elements of AP and now instead of searching for third element in the original input stream, you can look it up easily in **where**.

I always end algorithm questions with:Can we do better? I'm sure there's a better way, I will update this answer if I hit it.